# HTC Desire sticky power button

Tags: htc-desire, hardware, power-on

I have an HTC Desire that is 2 and a bit years old and in the hands of my wife and baby, now has a power button that barely works. Luckily the ROM I'm using allows the device to wake with the select button, but when the battery dies it is a real pain to power up.

Does anyone have any tips to fix it?

Comment: can you add what happened to it? Spilled soft drink? Take it apart &clean it.  Dropped the phone onto the pwr button?

Comment: @ce4 - no idea, could be baby dribble, dropped, thrown... anything.  Phone was mint conidtion after 2 years, then I gave it to my wife and now it looks like a bomb's gone off beside it...

Comment: ok. its maybe best to have so. look at it at a local store that also repairs phones and see if it can be fixed for a reasonable price.